# Firebase messaging's spawned isolate and main app - how to pass data(Web)?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

According to https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/
onBackgroundMessage(...) is running on its own isolate.

How do I pass data from that isolate (which automatically spawns and runs a top level function) to the main app **without using persistent storage** (sqlite/files) which isn't supported on the web platform?

Comment: You can use Hive as data storage which consistently works in the Web and on native platforms: https://pub.dev/packages/hive

Comment: @MaximSaplin Notice that while Hive is working on Web, once you open a box it's in memory (Main app memory to which the isolate doesn't any access to), so that any changes made at Firebase's spawned isolate don't reflect on the open box.

Comment: From my experience opening and closing boxes is fast, besides all APIa are async and you wouldn't notice UI stutter

Comment: I didn't claim that the UI will stutter. You might want to re-read what I said (no proper communication between the isolate and the main app). (as a sidenote not all the API is async in Hive, in fact accessing data in an opened box is not async [get for example])

Comment: Lazy boxes use async get(). The comment regarding stutter is in regards to the case when opening a box can take some time - e.g. 50ms. Such a delay when opening a box won't affect frame rate. Btw, Hive uses IndexedDB in the Web and it is one of the few pure Dart options for data persistance (SharedPreferences is another one yet slower) and which lets you cover all platforms with no need to write different code say for Web and Native. It also helps avoid JS interop and writing JS code.

Comment: In regards to isolates, there're no isolates in the Web but even when dealing with native platforms (not sure if those ones are in focus for you) cross-isolate communication (e.g. via SendPort/ReceivePort) won't solve the problem since main isolate cant accept any messages when the app goes to background.

Comment: I think that Hive isn't relevant since an open box (which is in main app memory) isn't being automatically updated. Unless you suggest to open and close all boxes every single time the app changes state to resumed? Notice that SharedPreferences which you mentioned right now suffer from the exact same issue (changes will not be reflected on the open SharedPreferences singleton which is in memory of main app).

Comment: Opening and closing box for each read or write operation. Take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter Web does not support isolates. You are likely looking in the wrong documentation tab. Still, what you are looking for may just not be supported yet.

> Web requires you to register a JavaScript Service Worker which runs in the background.

> Unfortunately we haven't yet been able to establish a proper way of communicating with the Service Worker and Flutter applications. Right now, all web background code must be executed in the JavaScript Service Worker file.

**EDIT:**

In order to share data between WebWorkers and the app, you can try using the awesome Drift library (formerly Moor).

- https://pub.dev/packages/drift
- https://drift.simonbinder.eu/web/

> You can offload the database to a background thread by using Web Workers. Drift also supports shared workers, which allows you to seamlessly synchronize query-streams and updates across multiple tabs!

You should be able to communicate with the background database web worker and save your data. If correctly setup, this will in turn update your frontend.

Maybe checkout this example: https://github.com/simolus3/moor/tree/develop/extras/web_worker_example

Comment: Interesting. It's not clear for me how to listen to a DB change on drift ,especially if it was changed by a different isolate or a background worker. If that isn't possible, and the only option is to refresh everything when the app resumes, then the same "solution" (quotes are there because it's kind of a hack) is possible for hive as well.

Comment: Drift tracks table updates in the background isolate (web worker) and informs client isolates about these updates, the clients can then (automatically) re-execute their queries for those changed tables. I have only used it in plain Dart so far but I assume from its description that works the same way in Web, even across tabs.

Comment: Will be awesome if you can share the code implementation of that informing :)

Comment: Not really because every query just does this out of the box when you watch it, you can look at basic query examples. - Drift let's you "watch" your queries with zero additional effort. Any query can be turned into an auto-updating stream that emits new items when the underlying data changes.